# Is Windows caching the URLs of internet shortcut files?

Tags: windows, shortcuts, url, links

Let's say I have links for two searches on the web: "search 1" and "search 2" on Google. The URLs would then be:

```
https://www.google.com/#q=search1
https://www.google.com/#q=search2
```

I create internet shortcuts for both of them, and place them in the same folder.

Now, I want to create copies of them. I copy the first shortcut and name it `1.url`; if I double-click on it, I get "search 1". I delete this copy and create a new copy of the "search 2" link. I rename it again to `1.url`. I double-click, but I get "search 1" again.

What's causing this behavior? Does Windows cache the URLs of `.url` (internet shortcut) files?

Comment: It reproduces on Win Xp - when link is copied it somehow loses its extension. And it still opens...

Comment: I'm on Windows 8 and I was able to reproduce this behavior. Maybe make it a general Windows tag?

Comment: Reproduced on Windows 7. Same question on StackOverflow: [Does Windows cache the contents of .url (Internet Shortcut) files?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3329139/434012)

Comment: Does it happen with any browser set as default?

Comment: Have you looked in the registry at the MRU keys?  This is one easy to view place where windows caches recently run programs.  I don't recall the key location, but a google search should find it.

Comment: The weirdest part is that the original URL is retained if the file is renamed to once more to something new. Must be an Explorer feature.

Comment: Windows 7, IE 10. I cannot recreate this.

Answer (score 2):

Same question is here.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329139/does-windows-cache-the-contents-of-url-internet-shortcut-files/15340839#15340839

Windows Caches your filenames in the MUICache which can be found in the registry.